# Identity Model Claims With XML Characters Within Them

Tags: wif, saml

I'd like to do something like

```
 outputIdentity.Claims.Add(new Claim("Claim1", "<test>Hi</test>"))
```

However the security node within the response header itself shows it as

```
<Attribute Name="Claim1"><AttributeValue>&lt;test&gt;Hi&lt;/test&gt;</AttributeValue></Attribute>
```

I know they are reserved XML characters getting translated but can't I specify that I want that node structure in my attribute?

NOTE:  I've also tried wrapping it in CDATA however it serializes that tag too.  When I replace the translated characters, it works.

Comment: Please clarify where you see that "the request shows itself as" with `&lt;` etc., i.e., as a properly formatted XML document: in a debugger? in an actual claim value? transmitted over HTTP to/from the browser? elsewhere?  In other words, why is this a problem?  I would expect to see exactly that XML to be sent from WIF-based STS via browser to claims-aware web application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Serialization of security tokens is done by the `SecurityTokenHandler` (in your case probably the `Saml11SecurityTokenHandler`).

If you want to customize serialization you have to overwrite the default behaviour by extending the `Saml11SecurityTokenHandler` class:

```
class CustomHandler : Saml11SecurityTokenHandler
{
    public Saml11SecurityTokenHandler()
      : base()
    {
    }

    public Saml11SecurityTokenHandler(SamlSecurityTokenRequirement samlSecurityTokenRequirement)
      : base(samlSecurityTokenRequirement)
    {
    }

    public Saml11SecurityTokenHandler(XmlNodeList customConfigElements)
      : base(customConfigElements)
    {
    }

    protected override void WriteAttribute(XmlWriter writer, SamlAttribute attribute)
    {
        // your code here
    }
}
```

You also have to add your custom security token handler in the web.config file:

```
<securityTokenHandlers>
  <add type="Your.Namespace.CustomHandler, Your.Dll.Name, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral" />
</securityTokenHandlers>
```

**EDIT**: removed `<clear />`

Comment: I'm starting to go down this path however any kind of SecurityTokenHandler I implement is giving me a The token Serializer cannot serialize 'Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.SessionSecurityToken'

Comment: Simply remove the `<clear />` from the securityTokenHandler section. I edited my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try wrapping the value in CDATA section?  As:

```
<![CDATA[<test>Hi</test>]]>
```

Not sure whether your SecurityTokenHandler class will handle that properly, but it's worth a try, and easier than introducing custom handlers.