# Custom Saml2SecurityTokenHandler - The token Serializer cannot serialize

Tags: wif, saml

For the sake of simplicity, I've implemented the following class:

```
public class CustomUserNamePasswordValidatorSecurityTokenHandler : UserNameSecurityTokenHandler {}
```

And I've enabled it configuration (and enabled proper configSection):

```
  <microsoft.identityModel>
    <service>
      <securityTokenHandlers>
        <clear />
        <add type="CustomUserNamePasswordValidatorSecurityTokenHandler" />       
      </securityTokenHandlers>
    </service>
  </microsoft.identityModel>
```

And performing an actual RP call against my STS yields (in service trace viewer):

**The token Serializer cannot serialize 'Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.SessionSecurityToken'.  If this is a custom type you must supply a custom serializer.**

If I comment out the configuration (so no token handler applys), everything works fine.  How do I supply this custom serializer?

NOTE:  There's a couple references to the issue in [this thread](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/Geneva/thread/ddd45b84-f0d4-48b2-9ce0-1042bea06193) however I don't see the resolution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Removing the `<clear />` on the securityTokenHandler section should suffice (I editied may answer on your [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6795371/identity-model-claims-with-xml-characters-within-them/6796425) accordingly, sorry).

`<clear />` removes all by default registered handlers (e.g. for the SessionSecurityToken).